# verilog changing random seed

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How do I change the seed for `$urandom_range` every time I am starting a new simulation. I tried so many things non worked.

```
always@(posedge tb_rd_clkh)
  begin
    $random(9);
    tbo9_ready_toggle_q <= $urandom_range(0, 1);
  end
```

Comment: What do you think `$random(9);` is supposed to mean?

Comment: Are you asking how to get a different seed for each simulation?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the seed using a flag like this:

> irun -seed seed_number

Or you can use a random seed:

> irun -seed random

I'm pretty sure every tool (Questa and VCS) has an option to do this. If you don't set a seed, it will default to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Set the seed value by using the conventional way before accessing the range of random numbers using urandom_range

```
  seed = 2;
  void'($urandom(seed));
```

Here the above code snippet will set the seed value to 2 for uramdom_range too and every time you run, random number generator creates the same sequence as long as the seed is same, you can find a working example at the [EDA-Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Si3)

**UPDATE:**
For your question how to set seed for urandom_range insde always block? A more generalized way as per SV [LRM IEEE 1800 - 2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) Section 18.13.3 srandom()

> The srandom() method allows manually seeding the RNG of objects or
>   threads.

Thus by making use of it created a simplified self contained example to show how to set seed inside always block

```
module dut(input clk,output reg [31:0] out);
  integer seed;
  assign seed = 10;
  always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
      $srandom(seed);
      out <= $urandom_range (10,1);
      $display ("out = %d",out);
    end
endmodule
```

You may want to try this out, the above example with tb can be found in the [link](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/HnG).

**Solution to your question**

In your code snippet you have to change `$random(9)` to `$srandom(9)` were 9 is the seed value

Comment: Thanks, but how come it is not working in always statement? I did the same thing like below, but it didn't work:                                      always@(posedge tb_rd_clkh)
  begin
   seed <= 3;
   rand_gen <= $urandom(seed); 
    tbo9_ready_toggle_q <= $urandom_range(0, 1);
  end

Comment: A different approach needs to be followed for always block, you can use the method mentioned in the updated answer